# How to sort a list by one string in alphabetical order in a JSON file

Tags: python, json

I need to sort a list of products by alphabetical order of the "category" string.

I have tried the `.sort()` but it gives error everytime.

This is the closest I got to making it work:

```
import json

with open("broken_database.json", "r", encoding="utf-8") as file:
    broken_database = json.load(file)
    for case in broken_database:
        case["category"] = sorted(case["category"], key = lambda category: category)

with open("broken_database.json", "w", encoding="utf-8") as file:
    json.dump(broken_database, file, indent=2)

print(broken_database)
```

I expected to get something like this:

```
{
    "id": 1911864,
    "name": "Møuse Gæmer Predætør ¢estus 510 Føx Pretø",
    "price": "699",
    "category": "Acessórios"
  },
 {
    "id": 9746439,
    "name": "Høme Theæter LG ¢øm ßlu-ræy 3D, 5.1 ¢ænæis e 1000W",
    "quantity": 80,
    "price": 2199,
    "category": "Eletrônicos"
  },
```

"Acessórios" first and then "Eletrônicos", but instead I got:

```
{
    "id": 3500957,
    "name": "Monitor 29 LG FHD Ultrawide com 1000:1 de contraste",
    "quantity": 18,
    "price": 1559.4,
    "category": [
      "E",
      "c",
      "e",
      "i",
      "l",
      "n",
      "o",
      "r",
      "s",
      "t",
      "\u00f4"
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 1911864,
    "name": "Mouse Gamer Predator cestus 510 Fox Preto",
    "price": 699.0,
    "category": [
      "A",
      "c",
      "e",
      "i",
      "o",
      "r",
      "s",
      "s",
      "s",
      "\u00f3"
    ],
    "quantity": 0
  }
]
```

I don't know where am I going wrong with this, the `.sort()` command is not working as it usually does and since it is the first time I try to use it in a JSON file I'm guessing there is something I'm missing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there. Try sorting the original list with a key function:

```
import json

with open("broken_database.json", "r", encoding="utf-8") as file:
    broken_database = json.load(file)
    broken_database.sort(key=lambda case: case["category"])

with open("broken_database.json", "w", encoding="utf-8") as file:
    json.dump(broken_database, file, indent=2)

print(broken_database)
```